# Add date to MKAnnotation title property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, mkannotation

I'm following the Nerd Ranch i0S Programming guide. I need to tag map annotations with the dates that they were created.

The following method I created overrides the MKAnnotation title property:

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)t
{
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

    // Obtain copy of passed title.
    [t retain];
    [title release];

    // Set required date format.
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

    title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", t, [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today]];
}
```

The app crashes at the last line of this method. Can someone please help?

Comment: What are the `retain` and `release` lines supposed to do? And what are you passing to this method, can you share the calling method? The problem may be that `t` is pointing into nowhere. Also, please share the crash log (the stack trace including the exception)

Comment: We need to see your crash log because your code as its written has problems, but shouldn't crash. You are over-retaining *t* and under-retaining *title*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSString’s `+stringWithFormat` returns an autoreleased object—since nothing else is taking ownership of it, your `title` is getting deallocated at the end of the run-loop cycle. You need to call `retain` on the new value of `title`, like this:

```
title = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", t, [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today]] retain];
```

or, alternatively, set it to a newly-allocated instance (hence not an autoreleased one), like this:

```
title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@", t, [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today]];
```

Comment: One more note—make sure that you call `[title release]` in your annotation’s `-dealloc`, or the memory it’s using will leak.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but would it help if you replaced the line

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
```

with

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dd-mm-yyyy"]];
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but this answer doesn't make sense at all!